# How to install gumbo in QT?

Tags: qt, gumbo

I just started to learn the QT recently, and I tried to parse a HTML while I found Gumbo could be a tool for this. But I don't know how to use it in my QT project. Can anyone help me here? Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of Gumbo? I never heard of Gumbo and found the [Gumbo installation instruction](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser#installation)

Comment: BTW, I just found [QGumboParser](https://github.com/lagner/QGumboParser). Next time, please search the web a little bit before asking here